# converting lots (100+) of analogue audio sources to RTP/UDP/'IP packets'?

Tags: audio, digital-audio, analog

I was 50/50 posting this here or the electronics board.. maybe I can get some help!

Basically I have a scenario where I'll have just over 100 analogue audio sources (50 in and 50 out) from 50 devices. I'll need to differentiate between the sources at a server to process each device individually. This is a communications thing, and has nothing to do with music.

Now.. I could invest in a huge mixer that converts from analogue to digital (ADC). But we're getting into big figures!

I've got a VoIP background, and know that the bandwidth on an ethernet port is certainly capable of accepting way more than 100 ports of audio.

So my question is.. Is there a small module I can purchase that will take an analogue signal and convert it to UDP and some sort of codec, and forward it on as network packets?

Is there anything you can suggest reading that may help?